# LoadURL at webview not work at android 10

Tags: android

I have a problem with this script.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

```
    private WebView webView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        WebSettings mWebSettings = webView.getSettings();
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.mypage.com");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }


            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        webView.reload();
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            view.loadData("Page not found", "text/html", "utf-8");
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

It's running well when I run it on under android 8. But it always shows an error page not found if I run at android 10. Someone can tell me why loadUrl not work at this case? Thank you for you help before...

Comment: Your question is not very specific. Please provide a minimal example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Additionally, you saying that there's no issue on Android 10, but also that there is an issue on Android 10; I'm guessing there's a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its problem from your url

on android 9 onward it required url using https, if you using http it will rejected

for example:

```
   webView.loadUrl("https://www.mypage.com");
```

or you can add permission `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on your manifest but its not guarented work but worth to try

```
manifest.xml


<manifest>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 

          <activity> your code </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have to try and the web page success load. But some functions such as the login process becomes not work anymore.

Comment: did you enable the javascript setting `mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code :

```
    public class Website extends AppCompatActivity {
        WebView webView;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    
            webView.loadUrl("https://yourURL.com/");
    
//check permission in case downloading file from webview
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
                }
            }
    
//method for downloading file to internal storage Download folder
            webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                            String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }});
        }
    
        public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Website.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
        
            }
    
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        //method to go back to previous page on click back button
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    
            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not work for me